# How to test Lightning component?

Tags: lightning

Since I am QA I have a question. How to test the Lightning component?
I know for sure that:
1) Check the design attributes
2) Is the component displayed on the page?
 
And what else and how else can you project?
I perform manual/functional testing

Answer (score 3):

You can always run the flow to do positive testing as they should work as expected.

Second, you can use [Lightning Testing Service](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/lightning_testing_intro.htm). Use Lightning Testing Service (LTS) to ensure your components perform as expected. LTS is a full suite of tools and services integrated with Salesforce DX to make testing easy.

There is a trailhead module for same which you can refer.
[Write Tests for Your Lightning Components](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/unit-testing-on-the-lightning-platform/lightning-component-tests)